# What was so bad about Bertrand's last line at the end of C3E3?

Tags: critical-role-show

At the end of episode 3 of the as-yet-unnamed campaign 3 of *Critical Role*, Bertrand Bell

> gets stabbed to death in an alleyway by the current villain.

> Travis states that before his character lost consciousness, he gasped out  "Lieve'tel..."  (This was the name of the *other* replacement character from *The Search for Grog*, played by Liam, who ended up hooking up with Bertrand; Travis appears to be suggesting that the two ended up having some sort of lasting relationship.)

When Travis said this, Matt and Laura both reacted to it with some rather uncomplimentary words.  It's not clear why, though.  What was offensive about Bertrand calling out for her?

Comment: The tag explicitly says it's "For *any* questions about the show Critical Role, *including plotting and show details*" (emphasis added).  We don't have a different site for web-streamed shows.  Possibly the closest thing on the network would be movies.SE, and it doesn't have a Critical Role tag.

Comment: I do not think this question should be closed, stacks answer questions based on the expertise of the experts of the stack. While this question could be asked on another stack, that doesn't mean it can't be asked here.

Comment: This looks to me like a lore question about the canonical D&D setting Exandria. We have a great many questions like this about the characters of the Forgotten Realms setting.

Comment: I'd be inclined to agree with closing as well. This is a little bit like asking what designer intent was but even moreso because most designer intent questions are far enough in the future for the people in question to have made comments about it (possibly). There's simply no way for an RPG stack member to answer this question barring them being Laura Bailey, Matthew Mercer, or other cast members (even excluding their newest member since he's only been brought on as of S3). At best any answer will be speculative and runs real close to being Opinion Based answers only.

Comment: @GuidingOlive If an answer breaks the rules isn't the correct answer to remove the answer, not the question? CR staff frequently talk about what happened in the games or how the games came to be. It's entirely possible that in an interview or on twitter they explained what they meant, or someone who is knowledgable about the show will understand their response.

Comment: @MagicalItemSmith Questions about designer intent *are* off topic, and if someone thinks this question falls under that, they should vote to close this question. I personally think the question is fine and will not be VTCing, but I can see why one might choose to do so.

Comment: The on-topicness of this question is being discussed on meta: [Is this question about a cast reaction to an in-character utterance from Critical Role on topic?](https://rpg.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/11833/is-this-question-about-a-cast-reaction-to-an-in-character-utterance-from-critica)

Comment: @MasonWheeler [Science Fiction and Fantasy has a category for Critical Role.](https://scifi.stackexchange.com/questions/tagged/critical-role) If this is closed here, it might fit there.

Comment: I’m voting to close this question because althought it is about a show about an RPG, it doesn't seem to be about playing RPG games. It also looks like "author's intent", and that's off topic here.

Answer (score 5):

In the context of Travis picking those words, I interpreted it as Travis' last attempt to get a reaction out of the other players at the table.  Travis played Bertrand for laughs and reactions pretty much always, and making his last words calling out the name of another players character to goad them on is perfectly in line with this. Matt and Laura likely called Travis names because they knew he was only saying this to make them upset.

In the context of this being Bertrand's last words, I think it is fitting, as it is the only woman we know truthfully had a relationship with Bertrand. He is a charlatan: constantly lying, boasting, and bragging in ways that usually get him in trouble when people learn the truth his words are attempting to hide.  I think it isn't unreasonable to assume that this was one of few, if not the only woman to treat him so kindly; enough so that she was this last thought.

Comment: @Trish Jon _is already_ providing citation. This answer's citing observed patterns from the show's lifetime to back up a conclusion derived from those patterns. Travis has a trend of trying to get a rise out of people ∴ this is an event of getting a rise of out of people. Bertrand has had these narrative experiences ∴ it seems evident that Betrand's last words are borne of those experiences. If Jon provided these conclusions without any explanation about the prior patterns exhibited by Travis and his character Bertrand _then_ we'd have nothing backing up those conclusions.

Comment: @doppelgreener The problem is that, once again, "I interpreted" and "I think" are brought in. Are you sure that's actually what Travis was doing with that character? That's why it's unsubstantiated. It also doesn't help in that there is no citation based on observed behavior. Providing a link out to time stamps of which Bertrand Bell was used in this way would go pretty far to at least provide that type of evidence.

Comment: @doppelgreener One could provide Episode numbers and times to prove a behavioral pattern. Without, this reads as speculation and fan theory. At the moment it is at best a threadbare allegaion - thus unsubstantiated.

Comment: While I think specific examples (assuming there are good clear ones and they aren't too onerous to find) would be a magnificent addition to this answer, let's leave that as a suggested improvement and the rest to voters. This seems like a reasonable analysis, showing both it's voice and its basis. And at least I'll leave a general reminder to be friendly and constructive.